# How can I make Kotlin-native executable with runtime debug information?

Tags: kotlin-native

In Personally, I am modifying and testing some features of the kotlin-native memory manager.
But, I am struggling to find a way to create an OSX XCode executable, including debugging information of the C++ sources in kotlin-native runtime. 
'kotlinc -g ..' generates only debug informations for Kotlin sources.
Please let me know how to build debugging version of runtime and link the debug information into sample kotlin apps. 
I am using Kotlin-native 1.3.72, and Xcode 11.5

Answer (score 1):

I think the only available option here is to re-build Kotlin/Native runtime with adding `-g` compiler option to the Gradle script. See [this file and line](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/build.gradle#L12-13), probably it should be the correct place.

Comment: I have already tried that. (with -g and -gdwarf2)<br>
But the output executable has no debug informations

Comment: How exactly you tried to do it? Just building the whole compiler again, or the only runtime? For the latter case, maybe you should try using `-Xruntime` konan compiler here.

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion? Maybe it works in windows-build but not in OSX. After build runtime with '-g' option, the application build fails with error. And after build runtime with '-gdwarf-2' whole debug information is disappeared.